# How to ignore dot in url

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

my program displays information about items from the database when I just type their name.
It works fine for IDs and most names except when the name contains a dot.

```
match 'show/:name' => 'show#displayinfo'
```

In the controller I have:

```
@details = Description.where(:name => params[:name] ).first
```

Along with conditions on what to do if name was not found

When I type something like `../show/Ruby` - it works fine
but `../show/a.b` displays an empty page and no errors except this in the development log:

```
Processing by ShowController#displayinfo as 
Parameters: {"name"=>"a"}
```

If I type `../show/a` this works as expected, no errors, no empty views.

Any way to solve this except renaming the items in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing)

```
match 'show/:name' => 'show#displayinfo', :format => false
```

should do it.

Comment: Not working for me in 2021 on Rails 6.1, even though [the docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing) still say this is supported.

Answer (score 1):

everything after the dot is usually considered the format of the request. ie html or json or whatever mimetype is configured in your rails application.

here is an example of how you can surpass this default behavior: http://zargony.com/2009/05/05/routing-parameters-with-a-dot

the basic trick is to use a greedy regex to parse the paramters.